# How to fix bug in 2D presentation of DAE.-models in Anylogic?

Tags: blender, anylogic, agent, presentation

I am working with Anylogic (Researcher) and have implemented several agents in my model.

Usually, I use standard presentations for my agents. But for two of them, I have created two DAE.-models with Blender. The integration to Anylogic has worked easily. But in my running model, the 2D presentation is missing (no presentation). 3D presentation still works.

I already checked the "Show presentation" - Button, re-installed Anylogic, and re-integrated the DAE.-models.

What do you think? Should I create in Blender a 2D view?

Comment: Can you see the small 2D represantation in the properties of the 3D object next to "Orientation"? If not, it may be some deeper issue with the dae file that AnyLogic cannot interpret correctly.

Comment: That's a good point. I can't see the 2D representation. Perhaps I need to check the Blender files. Thanks!